# Ambiguous error occured when I add a second order field using Zend Framework 1.6.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

When I echo the sql using `echo $select->__toString()`:

```
SELECT `a`.`ChannelID`,
       `a`.`CategoryID`,
       `a`.`Country`,
       `a`.`LocalName`,
       if((`a`.`Type` = 'FreeText'
           AND a.IsHybrid = 'YES'), 'Hybrid', if(`a`.`Type` = 'FreeText'
           AND a.IsHybrid = 'NO', 'FreeText', a.Type)) AS TYPE,
       `a`.`IsActive`,
       `a`.`LastChangeDate`
FROM `ProCatCountry` AS `a`
INNER JOIN `ProCat` AS `b` ON a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
ORDER BY FIELD(a.TYPE, 'Normal', 'Special', 'Structured'),TYPE ASC 
LIMIT 25
```

What I order by as the second field is the `TYPE` field which is calculated in the `if` clause. I added this because without using the second order field, there will be sorting problem, because the field `a.TYPE` is `ENUM`, so I have to fix the sort using a second order field.

But now I added the second field, I runs successfully and nicely when I use sql client like sqlyog, but when I use `return $this->_myAdapter->fetchAll($select);` to execute the sql, there come a `TYPE is ambiguous` error. I think the problem lies in the Zend Framework `fetchAll()` method, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `TYPE` as an `ORDER BY` Parameter because it is an only an `ALIAS` of your `IF` statement. You can make `TYPE` as an `ORDER BY` Parameter if it is in a sub-query. See my example below:

```
 SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT `a`.`ChannelID`,
           `a`.`CategoryID`,
           `a`.`Country`,
           `a`.`LocalName`,
           if((`a`.`Type` = 'FreeText'
               AND a.IsHybrid = 'YES'), 'Hybrid', if(`a`.`Type` = 'FreeText'
               AND a.IsHybrid = 'NO', 'FreeText', a.Type)) AS TYPE,
           `a`.`IsActive`,
           `a`.`LastChangeDate`
    FROM `ProCatCountry` AS `a`
    INNER JOIN `ProCat` AS `b` ON a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
    ORDER BY FIELD(a.TYPE, 'Normal', 'Special', 'Structured') ASC 
    LIMIT 25) AS A ORDER BY TYPE ASC
```